# Spring Integration WS: mock Endpoint to return response

Tags: spring, web-services, unit-testing, spring-ws

I have setup a Spring Integration flow configuration to send messages to an external web service and then unmarshalling the response and then doing some post processing based on the response object type.

I have the following `outbound-gateway` configuration:

```
<int:channel id="sendRequestChannel"/>
<ws:outbound-gateway request-channel="sendRequestChannel" uri="${send.ws.uri}" reply-channel="responseTransformer" >
    <ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="retryAdviceUserUpdateWs" />
    </ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
</ws:outbound-gateway>
```

Now, I want to test the flow and check that the correct post processing is triggered based on the response object.

Is there anyway in my integration test to mock the Endpoint response based on the message I'm sending?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should understand from which part  of your flow it would be better to mock and return the desired response.

1. You can inject `ChannelInterceptor` to the `sendRequestChannel` with `preSend` which returns `null`, to prevent the further process and `send` a message with desired response to the `responseTransformer`.
2. Another powerful option is to add one more `Advice` to the `<ws:request-handler-advice-chain>` and implement it as extension of `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice`.
3. And the last option which I see via Java code is a `mock` for `WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive` and inject it to the `<ws:outbound-gateway>`.
4. From other side I know that SoapUI has a tool to `mock` target service, so, you even don't need to do anything in Java, unless tests.

So, it up to you to choose the proper way to test you flow.

Comment: Thanks Artem, actually I do need to implement a mocked response in Java as I need to perform Integration Tests to test that at the end of the flow the input Message is persisted in the DB. I'll give a try to the options you wrote and see what's the one that best fits.